# error "type of this value must be known in this context" in pattern matching

Tags: rust

Consider the following example

```
fn main () {
    f("hello", true);
}

fn f(str: &str, sen: bool) {
    let s: &str = match sen {
        false => str,
        true => str.chars().map(|x| x.to_lowercase()).collect().as_slice()
    };
    println!("{}", s);
}
```

I'm getting this error

```
error: the type of this value must be known in this conntext                                                                                                                                                              
true => str.chars().map(|x| x.to_lowercase()).collect().as_slice()
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I'm a bit confused, doesn't the compiler know that the type of `str` is `&str` from the function definition? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error location is maybe confusing, the problem here is the `collect` method. It is generic for any `FromIterator` and in this case the compiler cat infer the type (what compiler sees is you need some type X implementing `FromIterator` that has an `as_slice` method producing a &str).

The second problem with this code that you are trying to return a reference to a local value (result of collect) from the match statement. You can't do that because that value has the lifetime of that block and is deallocated after, so the returned would be invalid.

One working solution (but it requires converting &str to String):

```
fn main () {
    f("hello", true);
}

fn f(str: &str, sen: bool) {
    let s: String = match sen {
        false => str.to_string(),
        true => str.chars().map(|x| x.to_lowercase()).collect()
    };
    println!("{}", s);
}
```

I don't know what you are trying to achieve in the end but take a look at `MaybeOwned` if this will be a function returning a slice (`&str`) or a `String`.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using temporary variables to store the `String` and bind s to `temp_var.as_slice()`. Not sure whether there's a better way though.